# is there any reason to use entity SQL over Linq?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Entity framework provides at least two ways to query data: Entity SQL and Linq?

Linq sounds like a better option.

Any reason one should care about Entity SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used EntitySQL in order to generate complex condition on the fly without using something like Predicate Builder. But i agree that Linq3Entities is better since you get compile time check on your query.

**EDIT**
In Entity SQL i can do this:

```
context.Entities.Where("it.Id IN { 1, 2, 3 }");
```

with it i build a string to add multiple condition with 'And' and 'Or'

You can also see the multiple post on StackOverflow about this: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647/linq-to-entities-vs-esql) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363761/entity-framework-entity-sql-vs-linq-to-entities)
or other link [Linq-to-SQL vs Linq-to-Entities : Revisited](http://naspinski.net/post/Linq-to-SQL-vs-Linq-to-Entities--Revisited.aspx) or [Choosing LINQ to Entities vs Entity SQL vs. EntityClient](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/choosing-linq-to-entities-vs-entity-sql-vs-entityclient/)

Comment: Do you have an example where EntitySQL is better than Linq